# Express Router.Post not sending back Json on Postman

Tags: javascript, api, express, postman, router

I am attempting to learn express and how to use postman and I'm following along a tutorial. Everything was going well until I tested router.get by sending dummy data to the server. I use postman to attempt to post to my localhost 500. Instead of getting a json back of the data in which I sent, I get a 200 status and nothing at the bottom of my screen. When i check the console upon hitting that route, this is logged to the console: http://undefined/api/members.

Mind you, I have no trouble using router.get to receive a json of all my members and I have no trouble receiving a json by searching with just the member ID. But for whatever reason router.post isn't working for me. I suspect this has to do with the body parser. But I'm not sure why specifically it isn't working. Please help.

This is how I set up my app file:

```
const express = require('express')
    const app = express()
    const path = require('path');
    const logger = require('./middleware/logger')
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser')



    app.use(logger)

    app.use('/api/members', require('./routes/api/members'))

    app.use(bodyParser.json())

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))



    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`Server started on port ${[PORT]}`)
    })
```

The following is how I set up my router file

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const members = require('../../Members')


router.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.json(members);
})


router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    const found = members.some(member => member.id === parseInt(req.params.id));

    if(found){
    res.json(members.filter(member => member.id === parseInt(req.params.id)))
    } else { 
        res.status(400).json({msg: `No member with the id of ${req.params.id}`})
    }
})


router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.body)
})



module.exports = router
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "expressCrashCourse",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index",
    "dev": "nodemon index"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routes are processed in order so if you want the body-parser middleware to be active for your `.post()` route, the middleware has to be BEFORE it.  So, change this:

```
app.use('/api/members', require('./routes/api/members'))

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
```

to this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))

app.use('/api/members', require('./routes/api/members'))   // <== after your middleware
```

As it was, it was hitting your route before the middleware got a chance to run and thus `req.body` was still not populated with the body contents.